# Не работает интерпретатор для javascript Conemu

Tags: javascript, консоль, интерпретатор

Начал изучать php по вебинару. Хотел запустит интерпретатор javascript ConEmu - вот, что выдает.

> Ошибка в синтаксисе команды. Current directory: E:\Доп\ConEmu Command
>   to be executed: "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /C  ConEmuC:
>   Root process was alive less than 10 sec, ExitCode=1. Press Enter or
>   Esc to close console...

И может, есть какой-нибудь нормальный интерпретатор уже настроенный под javascript?

Еще не понимаю, почему в этом интерпретаторе **print("строка")** выводит строку, но если html файл, содержащий скрипт "**... print("строка") ...**" запустить в браузере mozilla, он открывает печать документа. Также некоторые функции **putstr("")** в интерпретаторе работают, а браузере нет

Comment: ConEmu - это просто эмулятор терминала(командной строки) каким образом он связан с javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос, решился, закинул программу в корневую папку. Хотя логики так и не понял, почему не работало во внутренней.

А реально все так и делают, используют ConEmu для запуска javascript? Или есть какие-нибудь более удобные способы?

Comment: Нет, что-то через одно место работает программа ConEmu. Может кто-нибудь объяснить, неужели нельзя обойтись без этой программы ConEmu? Нафига она, неужели все javascript-овцы сидят на этой программе?